# how to download byte data (pdf) response given by server in extjs4.1

Tags: php, download, extjs4.1, tcpdf

i have some fields in panel. am sending user entries to the server using ajax request. In server side am using php to generate pdf[using **tcpdf**] file based on the entries made by user.

below is the code snippet of ajax request.

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
          url: 'tcpdf3.php',
          method : 'POST',

          params : {
                     fromDate : Ext.encode(Ext.getCmp('FromDate').value),
                     username : Ext.getCmp('uname').value
                   } 
          success : function(){
            // how to handle byte response giving by server . i.e want to download the pdf file(byte stream response) generated by server.
          }
          failure : function(){

          }
         });
```

ajax request carrying user entries is going to server correctly. And in server side the php file "tcpdf3.php" will give byte strems as response(i.e pdf file),upto this all is working fine. Am finding difficult how to handle the byte stream response given by server.i.e i want to download the pdf file generated.
below is the response given by server.

[image]

can someone please help me out of this.